# Install and configure Backendless Standalone on a PC?

Tags: backendless, mbaas, coderunner

After Parse.com announced they're closing I've decided to find a new mbaas, and I found Backednless.

I downloaded their standalone version and installed it on my PC.

I would like to configure it in some way, in order to be able to deploy my custom Java/PHP server code from CodeRunner on InteliJ IDE to the Standalone version running on my PC.

Could show me how do you configure the config files properly, please?